# KVM Virtual Machine high load average but low cpu and ram usage-why?

Tags: nginx

I have a web server with nginx and php-fpm 5.6. It is one virtual machine of KVM. Here is ovs between VMs. The parameters of this Vm are : 4 CPU, 6GB RAM and 50 GB disk with raw, Debian 8.6. There are every 15 minutes load average increases and number of php-fpm processes also increases.
I have tested and deleted all jobs from cron. When load average increases input and output traffic accordingly. How can I solve this problem ? I already spent 3 days on it.
Here is my screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1, The host's of VM high too high load and VM can't get enough resource. Example: If your host's hard drive load percentage too high, your VM must be wait for free I/O resource -> high IOWAIT.

2, Try to change KVM disk cache type: "write back". **Just if your raid controller have a battery protected memory!**

Comment: It is without raid controller